# VBA For Each cell In Range Format as Percentage

Tags: vba, excel, loops, number-formatting, percentage

I've looked around for this and it seems so simple, yet I can't get it to work.

I have a table and one column needs to be formatted as a percentage. Below is my code but it is not formatting the cells, it just leaves them as the decimal.

I think this is because `cell`, even though declared as a range, is actually the value of the cell so I don't know how to refer to that range.

My `returnRebate` variable is declared as a range and the loop is looping through the correct range.

Code:

```
Dim cell As Range, p As Double
For Each cell In returnRebate
    p = cell.Value

    If p <> 0 And p > 1 Then
        p = p * 0.01
        cell.Value = p
        cell.NumberFormat = "Percent"    'Not formatting here
     ElseIf p < 1 And p > 0 Then
        'do nothing to it
    Else
        cell.Value = vbNullString
    End If
Next
```

Comment: try replacing .NumberFormat='Percent' with .NumberFormat="0.00%"

Comment: @RyanL omg I knew it was simple! I thought I had tried that but I guess not

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try replacing `.NumberFormat='Percent'` with `.NumberFormat="0.00%"`

Comment: I used `.NumberFormat="0%"` as I did not want the additional decimals. Still works great!

Comment: @cheshire Just tried with Office Prof 2013 and no problem with the decimal points, FWIW. Maybe version dependent (?)